# Gitlab CI - find the pipeline variables used

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

When you run a pipeline from the Gitlab UI, you are open to add variables to the run:

> [image]

From the overview of finished pipelines, is there a way to find the set variables and values of specific runs?

Comment: You can echo the variable in the job and check the value in the logs

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, these are one time variables you set by running a pipeline manually. You cannot view the the variables in the UI. Instead, like @Origin said you can echo the variable in the job.

example:

```
script:
    - '& echo "$MY_VARIABLE"'
```

I would recommend you to save your variables in the default CI/CD Settings. (Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables). There you can set, save, protect (from other user roles) and view them for sure. These variables will be used in any pipeline run you do.